# Android: How do you set a spinner to change focus to the next EditText box down after a selection has been made?

Tags: android, xml

I am working on an app that has multiple edittext fields and spinners and i want the focus to be switched to the next edittext box down when a selection is made from the spinner above.

Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an [ItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)) to your spinner, and call requestFocus on the next editBox.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a old question. but it might help someone

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener { view: View, _ ->
  if (context is Activity) {
    Util.hideSoftKeyboard(context as Activity)
    (context as Activity).currentFocus?.let {
      if (it.hasFocus() && it is EditText) {
        it.isFocusable = false
        it.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
        it.clearFocus()
        it.isFocusable = true
        it.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
      }
    }
  }
  spinner.requestFocus()
}
```